# Convert CSV into JSON. How do I keep values with the same Index?

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dictionary

I am using this database: https://cpj.org/data/killed/?status=Killed&motiveConfirmed%5B%5D=Confirmed&type%5B%5D=Journalist&localOrForeign%5B%5D=Foreign&start_year=1992&end_year=2019&group_by=year

I have preprocessed it into this csv (showing only 2 lines of 159):

```
year,combinedStatus,fullName,sortName,primaryNationality,secondaryNationality,tertiaryNationality,gender,photoUrl,photoCredit,type,lastStatus,typeOfDeath,status,employedAs,organizations,jobs,coverage,mediums,country,location,region,state,locality,province,localOrForeign,sourcesOfFire,motiveConfirmed,accountabilityCrossfire,accountabilityAssignment,impunityMurder,tortured,captive,threatened,charges,motive,lengthOfSentence,healthProblems,impCountry,entry,sentenceDate,sentence,locationImprisoned
1994,Confirmed,Abdelkader Hireche,,,,,Male,,,Journalist,,Murder,Killed,Staff,Algerian Television (ENTV),Broadcast Reporter,Politics,Television,Algeria,Algiers,,,Algiers,,Foreign,,Confirmed,,,Partial Impunity,No,No,No,,,,,,,,,
2014,Confirmed,Ahmed Hasan Ahmed,,,,,Male,,,Journalist,,Dangerous Assignment,Killed,Staff,Xinhua News Agency,"Camera Operator,Photographer","Human Rights,Politics,War",Internet,Syria,Damascus,,,Damascus,,Foreign,,Confirmed,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

And I want to make this type of JSON out of it:

```
"Afghanistan": {"year": 2001, "fullName": "Volker Handloik", "gender": "Male", "typeOfDeath": "Crossfire", "employedAs": "Freelance", "organizations": "freelance reporter", "jobs": "Print Reporter", "coverage": "War", "mediums": "Print", "photoUrl": NaN}, "Somalia": {"year": 1994, "fullName": "Pierre Anceaux", "gender": "Male", "typeOfDeath": "Murder", "employedAs": "Freelance", "organizations": "freelance", "jobs": "Broadcast Reporter", "coverage": "Human Rights", "mediums": "Television", "photoUrl": NaN}
```

The problem is that Afghanistan (as you can see in the link) has had many journalist deaths. I want to list all these killings under the Index 'Afghanistan'. However, as I currently do it, only the last case (Volker Handloik) in the csv file shows up. How can I get it so every case shows up?

this is my code atm

```
import pandas as pd
import pprint as pp
import json

# list with stand-ins for empty cells
missing_values = ["n/a", "na", "unknown", "-", ""]

# set missing values to NaN
df = pd.read_csv("data_journalists.csv", na_values = missing_values, skipinitialspace = True, error_bad_lines=False)

# columns
columns_keep = ['year', 'fullName', 'gender', 'typeOfDeath', 'employedAs', 'organizations', 'jobs', 'coverage', 'mediums', 'country', 'photoUrl']

small_df = df[columns_keep]

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    print(small_df)

# create dict with country-column as index
df_dict = small_df.set_index('country').T.to_dict('dict')

print(df_dict)

# make json file from the dict
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(df_dict, fp)

    # use pretty print to see if dict matches the json example in the exercise
 pp.pprint(df_dict)
```

I want to include all of these names (and more) in the JSON under the index Afghanistan

[image]

I think I will need a list of objects that is attached to the index of a country so that every country can show all the cases of journalists death instead of only 1 (each time being replaced by the next in the csv) I hope this is clear enough

Comment: So you want the country as the first level of your json, then all the related journalists inside it?

Comment: yes indeed! @micric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll keep your code until the definition of small_df.

After that, we perform a groupby on the 'country' column and use pd.to_json on it:

```
country_series = small_df.groupby('country').apply(lambda r : r.drop(['country'], axis=1).to_json())
```

country_series is a pd.Series with the countries as index.
After that, we create a nested dictionary, so that we have a valid json object:

```
fullDict = {}
for ind, a in country_series.iteritems():
    b = json.loads(a)
    c = b['fullName']
    smallDict = {}
    for index, journalist in c.items():
        smallDict[journalist] = {}
        for i in b.keys():
            smallDict[journalist][i] = b[i][index]
    fullDict[ind] = (smallDict)
```

The nomenclature in my part of code is pretty bad, but I tried to write all the steps explicitly so that things should be clear.

Finally, we write the results to a file:

```
with open('result.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(fullDict, f)
```

Comment: I currently get the error: ```NameError: name 'df_series' is not defined```

Comment: sorry, that is supposed to be country_series, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!